# Replacing for loop for higher efficiency

Tags: r

I'm trying to find an efficient way to replace a for loop in my code. I've found a workaround but  I'm sure there is a more "R-friendly" way to do this.

```
df<-structure(list(YY = c(2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021), DD = c(6, 
13, 19, 28, 3), MM = c("Fev", "Fev", "Fev", "Fev", "Mar"), Date = structure(c(18664, 
18671, 18677, 18686, 18689), class = "Date"), `ID (FIFA)` = c("FRA D1", 
"FRA D1", "FRA D1", "FRA D1", "FRA D1"), Country = c("France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France"), League = c("Ligue 1", 
"Ligue 1", "Ligue 1", "Ligue 1", "Ligue 1"), Season = c("2020/2021", 
"2020/2021", "2020/2021", "2020/2021", "2020/2021"), HOME = c("Lyon", 
"Lyon", "Brest", "Marseille", "Lyon"), AWAY = c("Strasbourg", 
"Montpellier", "Lyon", "Lyon", "Rennes"), `Final Scores` = c(3, 
1, 2, 1, 1), ...12 = c(0, 2, 3, 1, 0), ...13 = c("H", "A", "A", 
"D", "H"), ...14 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), `ET/Pen/Awd` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    `1st Half Scores` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), ...17 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), ...18 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), ...19 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2nd Half Scores` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...21 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...22 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), ...23 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), FTMoneyline...24 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...25 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...26 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Payout, %...27` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), FTMoneyline...28 = c(1.45, 
    1.38, 6.5, 5, 1.61), ...29 = c(5.25, 5.5, 4.85, 4.2, 4.4), 
    ...30 = c(8, 8, 1.5, 1.7, 5.9), `Payout, %...31` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `FT TG 2.5...32` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...33 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `FT TG 2.5...34` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ...35 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), OUTCOME = c(1, 3, 
    3, 2, 1), REFGAME = c("G236038", "G236098", "G236155", "G236247", 
    "G236276"), m1 = c(4.9, 4.96, 4.28333333333333, 3.63333333333333, 
    3.97), sd = c(3.28899680753874, 3.34287301583533, 2.54771139129481, 
    1.72143351115671, 2.17708520733572), indxcol = c(1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L), sp1 = c(-3.8, -4.12, 1.65, 0.8, -2.79), sp2 = c(2.75, 
    2.5, -3.35, -2.5, 1.5), ovr = c(0.513136288998362, 3.14558629776023, 
    2.66983875231297, 2.63305322128851, 1.78822651188164), wavg = c(0.357142857142857, 
    0.369623655913978, 0.377431906614786, 0.385321100917431, 
    0.36943744752309), ospr = c(5.51724137931035, 5.79710144927536, 
    4.33333333333333, 2.94117647058824, 3.66459627329193)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The objective of my script is to count for each HOME team how many times in the previous games it was the bookmaker's lowest decimal odds (odds are in col df[28:30]), and how many times it actually corresponded to the OUTCOME of the game.
This way I can get an accuracy ratio (r/t*100).

Here is the code with the for loop part I want to replace:

```
    if(is.null(nrow(df))|nrow(df)==0){
      r<-0
      return(r)
    }
    r<- 0
    t<- 0
    for(i in nrow(df):1){
      if(grep(team,df[i,])==9 & which.min(df[i,28:30])[[1]]==1){
        t<-t+1
        if(df[i,"OUTCOME"]==1){
          r<-r+1
        }
      } else if(grep(team,df[i,])==10 & which.min(df[i,28:30])[[1]]==3){
        t<-t+1
        if(df[i,"OUTCOME"]==3){
          r<-r+1
        }
      }
    }
    if(r==0 | t==0){
      return(0)
    }
    return(r/t*100)
```

And here is the workaround I've found but it doesn't look optimal:

```
    r<- 0
    t<- 0
    df1<- df[grepl(team,df$HOME) & apply(df[28:30],1,which.min)==1,]
    if(is.null(nrow(df1))|nrow(df1)==0){
      r<-0
      return(r)
    }
    r1 <-df1[df1["OUTCOME"]==1,]
    df2<- df[grepl(team,df$AWAY) & apply(df[28:30],1,which.min)==3,]
    if(is.null(nrow(df2))|nrow(df2)==0){
      r<-0
      return(r)
    }
    r2<- df2[df2["OUTCOME"]==3,]
    t<- sum(nrow(df1),nrow(df2))
    r<-sum(nrow(r1),nrow(r2))
    if(r==0 | t==0){
      return(0)
    }
    return(r/t*100)
```

How could I update this in a "R-friendly" way?

Following the comment of @DaveArmstrong, below is the output just after the last `group_by`:

```
structure(list(obs = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L
), place = c("home", "away", "home", "away", "home", "away", 
"home", "away", "home", "away"), team = c("Lyon", "Strasbourg", 
"Lyon", "Montpellier", "Brest", "Lyon", "Marseille", "Lyon", 
"Lyon", "Rennes"), r = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
    team = c("Brest", "Lyon", "Marseille", "Montpellier", "Rennes", 
    "Strasbourg"), .rows = list(5L, c(1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 9L), 7L, 
        4L, 10L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.16

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] neuralnet_1.44.2     class_7.3-15         gmodels_2.18.1       viridis_0.5.1        viridisLite_0.3.0   
 [6] plotly_4.9.1         gridExtra_2.3        slackr_1.4.2         qqplotr_0.0.4        ggplot2_3.3.0       
[11] odds.converter_1.4.8 e1071_1.7-2          tibble_2.1.3         readxl_1.3.1         dplyr_0.8.5         
[16] plyr_1.8.4           tidyr_1.1.3         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3        cellranger_1.1.0  pillar_1.4.3      compiler_3.6.1    DEoptimR_1.0-8    tools_3.6.1      
 [7] digest_0.6.25     jsonlite_1.6.1    lifecycle_0.2.0   gtable_0.3.0      pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.10     
[13] cli_2.0.2         rstudioapi_0.11   yaml_2.2.0        withr_2.1.2       httr_1.4.0        gtools_3.8.2     
[19] htmlwidgets_1.5.1 vctrs_0.3.6       grid_3.6.1        tidyselect_1.1.0  data.table_1.12.6 glue_1.3.1       
[25] robustbase_0.93-7 R6_2.4.1          fansi_0.4.1       gdata_2.18.0      purrr_0.3.3       magrittr_1.5     
[31] ellipsis_0.3.0    htmltools_0.4.0   scales_1.1.0      MASS_7.3-51.4     assertthat_0.2.1  colorspace_1.4-1 
[37] utf8_1.1.4        lazyeval_0.2.2    munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option:

```
names(df)[c(28:30)] <- c("odds1", "odds2", "odds3")
df2 <- df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(min_2830 = which.min(c(odds1, odds2, odds3))) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  group_by(HOME) %>% 
  mutate(r_home = as.numeric(min_2830 == 1 & OUTCOME == 1)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  group_by(AWAY) %>% 
  mutate(r_away = as.numeric(min_2830 == 3 & OUTCOME == 3)) %>%  
  select(HOME, AWAY, r_home, r_away) %>% 
  set_names(c("team_home", "team_away", "r_home", "r_away")) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(obs=1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-obs, names_pattern="(.*)_(.*)", 
               names_to = c(".value", "place")) %>% 
  group_by(team) %>% 
  summarise(r = cumsum(r)) %>% 
  mutate(game = seq_along(r), 
         pct = (r/game)*100)
  

df2
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
# # Groups:   team [6]
#   team            r  game   pct
#   <chr>       <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 Brest           0     1   0  
# 2 Lyon            1     1 100  
# 3 Lyon            1     2  50  
# 4 Lyon            2     3  66.7
# 5 Lyon            2     4  50  
# 6 Lyon            3     5  60  
# 7 Marseille       0     1   0  
# 8 Montpellier     0     1   0  
# 9 Rennes          0     1   0  
# 10 Strasbourg      0     1   0
```

```
sessionInfo()

R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] modelr_0.1.8    forcats_0.5.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.3     purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.4.0     tidyr_1.1.2    
 [8] tibble_3.0.5    ggplot2_3.3.2   tidyverse_1.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.4.7     compiler_4.0.3   dbplyr_1.4.3     tools_4.0.3     
 [7] jsonlite_1.7.1   lubridate_1.7.9  lifecycle_0.2.0  nlme_3.1-149     gtable_0.3.0     lattice_0.20-41 
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_0.4.10     reprex_0.3.0     cli_2.2.0        DBI_1.1.0        rstudioapi_0.11 
[19] haven_2.3.1      withr_2.3.0      xml2_1.3.2       httr_1.4.2       fs_1.4.1         generics_0.1.0  
[25] vctrs_0.3.6      hms_0.5.3        grid_4.0.3       tidyselect_1.1.0 glue_1.4.2       R6_2.5.0        
[31] fansi_0.4.2      readxl_1.3.1     magrittr_2.0.1   backports_1.1.10 scales_1.1.1     ellipsis_0.3.1  
[37] rvest_0.3.6      assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-1 utf8_1.1.4       stringi_1.5.3    munsell_0.5.0   
[43] broom_0.5.6      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: This is indeed the approach I was looking for. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello @DaveArmstrong, I'm having trouble getting the dataframe. I'm getting an error before the last summarise call: Error: Column `r` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 5. I've tried using rowwise after group_by but couldn't make it work. Do you have an idea ? thank you

Comment: I don't think `rowwise` will work.  What does your data set look like if you stop after the `group_by(team)` operation?

Comment: I've added the  `dput` in my question since it was too long for a comment.

Comment: If I call that data frame that you added `tmp` and then proceed with the next steps, I get the output in the answer.  I posted the results of `sessionInfo()` in my answer.  Are there any notable differences in package versions with what you're using?

Comment: I'm still having the same error even when using a data frame. I've posted my `sessionInfo()` in my question as well.

Comment: I think if you update `dplyr` it should work.  I installed R 3.6.1 and then installed the newest available version of `dplyr` and it worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229792/discussion-between-m-o-and-davearmstrong).